# x-- operation in c,why our value of b is decreasing and equal to '2' but our value of c is not change

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a = 1, b = 3, c = 1, p;
    if ((a || c--) && (c && b--)) printf("%d", b);
    printf("%d %d %d", a, b, c);
    scanf("%d", &p);
    return 0;
}
```

This c code segment's output is --> 2 1 2 1;
so why our value of b is decreasing and equal to '2' but our value of c is not change and equal to '1' i could not understant,i thought c would be '0'.

Comment: Read about *short-circuit evaluation*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a` is `1` so the second part of the first `(..)` is not executed. Value of `c` doesn't change.

Now `c` is 1 but as it is true, the second statement `b--` is executed also. (as `b` is `3` both of them is truthy).The whole conditional expression evaluates to true. That's why the result 2 1 2 1.

Because in an `or` conditional expression if any of the expression results in truthy value it short circuits and other expressions are not executed. `||` works from left to right.

`exp1 || exp2`  - if `exp1` is non zero then `exp2` will not be executed. As the whole condition evaluates to true.

But in the case of `&&` all the expressions must be truthy.

`e1 && e2 && e3` will be true if `e1` is true and `e2` is true and `e3` is true.

And if any of them is false, suppose `e1` then `e2` and `e3` wont be executed further. Because there is no way their result will make the condition true.

Both `&&` and `||` guarantees left to right evaluation.

#### Intuition-

You can consider `||` and `&&` (`logical or` and `logical and`)operator to be lazy. They will work as much as they need to know whether the whole expression is true.

for example `a || b || c` where `a = 0, b = 1, c =0`..it first checks whether `a` is true or false. It finds out `a` is false. So it has to check more. Then it sees `b` and it is `1`, it's true - then it doesn't check anymore.

Same goes with `&&` (logical and) but with falsy values.

This is known as *short-circuit-evaluation*.

Answer (score 0):

The `||` and `&&` operators have a behavior called **short-circut evaluation**.  What this means is that if the result of the operator can be determined by evaluating only the first operand, the second operand will not be evaluated.

In the case of the first subexpression:

```
(a||c--)
```

The value of `a` is 1, so the result of the `||` will be 1, regardless of the value of the right operand.  So `c--` is not evaluated and is therefore not decremented.

The above expression is the left side of a `&&` operand.  At this point the result of the operator is not yet known, so next the right side is evaluated:

```
(c&&b--)
```

The value of `c` at this point is 1, so the right hand side `b--` must be evaluated.  That has a value of 3, plus a side effect that decrements `b`.  So the expression is `1 && 3` which evaluates to 1.  This results in the entire expression evaluating to true, so the value of `b` (2) is printed.